# set row number to document and get data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a series of files and I have to separate and display part of the text

my code is :

```
path = 'C:\\Bot\\*.log' 
files = glob.glob(path) 
nlines = 0
for name in files: 
    try: 
        with open(name) as f:
            for line in f :
                 nlines += 1
                 if (line.find("Total") >= 0):
                     print(line)
```

I need a text that is saved in the file after the line number is obtained.
With the above code, I have access to the line number but I do not have access to some subsequent lines
How to access the next line value??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `next()` to read:

```
path = 'C:\\Bot\\*.log' 
files = glob.glob(path) 
nlines = 0
for name in files: 
    try: 
        with open(name) as f:
            for line in f:
                 nlines += 1
                 if (line.find("Total") >= 0):
                      for i in range(6):
                          print(next(f))
```

Comment: I want the values of the lines that are after the line that contains Total

Comment: If you find useful please upvote and accepts the answer It means a lot to me

Comment: Unfortunately for your solution only the next line after this line is displayed
While I need up to 6 lines after this

Comment: what about now ?

Answer (score 2):

```
path = 'C:\\Bot\\*.log' 
files = glob.glob(path) 
nlines = 0
for name in files: 
    try: 
        with open(name) as f:
            for line in f:
                 nlines += 1
                 if (line.find("Total") >= 0):
                      print(next(f))
```

I think it is a better solution to this problem